# JRE fatal error after shrinking with Proguard

Tags: java, jvm, proguard

I'm bundling the JRE with my JavaFX application on Mac using [gradle-macappbundle](https://github.com/crotwell/gradle-macappbundle). I'm trying to reduce the size of the JRE so I don't have to include the full ~200 MB. I have followed the instructions in the Java8 [README](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-8-readme-2095710.html) to remove some optional components.

After the macappbundle plugin creates the .app, I want to run Proguard on the JRE(I'm using the gradle plugin for it) to remove even more unused classes.

My current proguard rules:

```
task shrinkJRE(type: ProGuardTask, dependsOn: 'createApp') {
    injars "build/macApp/"
    outjars "build/libs/pro/"

    keep "class java.** { *; }"

    ignorewarnings()
    dontobfuscate()
    dontoptimize()
}
```

This produces a JRE about 45 MB.

But after doing `chmod +x` on the `JavaAppLauncher` executable and running it, it shows this error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000010c6025e4, pid=86901, tid=0x0000000000002303
#
# JRE version:  (8.0_181-b13) (build )
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x5825e4]  universe_post_init()+0x6a9
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /cores/core or core.86901
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/rishiraja/hs_err_pid86901.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Abort trap: 6 (core dumped)
```

Could anyone help me find the cause of this error?

My guess is that I'm missing some required classes for the JRE, so what are some classes I might also need to "keep"?

Comment: First of all, the license disallows to remove or change anything in JRE except Optional Files. Furthermore, JRE requires much more than just java.* classes, e.g. sun.*, com.sun.*, jdk.* etc.

Comment: As apangin said, you are not allowed to redistribute such a modified JRE. If it is only for your own environment, you’re wasting your time. The JVM loads most of the classes from the optimized archive `classes.jsa` (`rt.jar` could be replaced with an empty file), unless the jar files have a newer timestamp. See [Class Data Sharing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/class-data-sharing.html). Compare also with [the documentation for newer versions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/vm/class-data-sharing.htm) which is more exhaustive about controlling the contained classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The officially supported alternative to doing is now [jlink](https://openjdk.org/jeps/282) and [jpackage](https://openjdk.org/jeps/392). Using the [gradle plugin](https://github.com/beryx/badass-jlink-plugin) for jlink makes it very easy to produce small packages for distribution.